# Dynamically add a Highchart point while preserve categories

Tags: highcharts

I have the following chart:
[image]

```
{
    "chart": {
        "type": "bar"
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": "categories": ["week 5", "week 4", "week 3", "week 2", "week 1"]
    },
    "series": [{
            "name": "Building Total HVAC Power",
            "data": [4.12, 5.32, 5.44, 5.32, 5.32]
        }, {
            "name": "Building Total Lighting Power",
            "data": [12.12, 11.32, 12.23, 13.42, 15.21]
        }, {
            "name": "Building Total Plug Power",
            "data": [11.21, 12.23, 11.31, 11.12, 12.32]
        }
    ]
}
```

**The category labels (i.e. Week 1 to Week 5) are relative durations of time in the past, and should always remain the same because they are relative to present time.  When a week of time has expired, I will have new values for the current week (i.e. Week 1) and wish to update the displayed Week 1's values with these new values.  Note that now that a week has gone by, Week 2 needs to be updated with the original Week 1's values, and the same goes for Week 3 being updated with the original Week 2 values, etc. It should act exactly like using addPoint() with shift for a xAxis datatime chart except display these relative date labels instead of actual dates.**

```
[
    {"name": "Building Total HVAC Power", "value": 5.43},
    {"name": "Building Total Lighting Power", "value": 14.12},
    {"name": "Building Total Plug Power", "value": 11.42}
]
```

My attempt to do so is as follows:

```
function updateChart(highchart, newData) {
    var categories = this.highchart.xAxis[0].categories;
    for (var s = 0; s < highchart.series.length; s++) {
        highchart.series[s].addPoint(newData.series[s].value, false, true);
    }
    highchart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
    highchart.redraw();
}
```

However, as seen the category names are not being preserved.  My hopes were that `highchart.xAxis[0].setCategories()` would update them to the initial correct values, but that isn't the case.  How can I add a point while not changing the category labels?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposal of solution for your requirement, please check it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/93u64wrn/

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  chart.series.forEach(s => {
    newDataSet.forEach(data => {
      if (data.name === s.name) {
        s.points.forEach(p => {
          if (p.category === 'week 1') {
            p.update({
              y: data.value
            })
          }
        })
      }
    })
  })
})
```

EDIT

---

So here is my another proposal after clarifying the requirements:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/La7ow9mc/

```
  chart.series.forEach(s => {
    newDataSet.forEach(data => {
      if (data.name === s.name) {
        let newData = s.yData;
        newData.shift();
        newData.push(data.value);

        s.update({
            data: newData
        })
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian,  Your solution doesn't provided the desired results.  I apologize as I expect I did not appropriately describe how the chart should be updated.  I've since edited the original post and bolded the relevant changes.

Comment: Ah, so simple once you see it!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're adding a point and removing the first point afterwards (with the shift parameter). Instead you should update the existing data points of week 1:

```
function updateChart(highchart, newData) {
    var categoryIndex = highchart.xAxis[0].categories.indexOf('week 1');
    for (var s = 0; s < highchart.series.length; s++) {
        highchart.series[s].data[categoryIndex].update(newData.series[s].value);
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jne8m62h/)

Comment: Thanks Felix,  Looks like my approach works if using datetime (which wasn't what I was asking about), but what you say makes sense when using categories and I will check it out.

Comment: While your solution updates week 1 ago, week 2 still needs to be updated with week 1, week 3 with week 2, etc.  Intent is to act like datatime but instead of displaying a absolute time on the axis, display a relative time (i.e. x weeks ago).  Seems like `addPoint()` with shift "might" be more appropriate provided the displayed categories can be changed.